# activating LV 'pve/data' failed: Check of pool pve/data failed (status:1). Manual repair required! (500)

Tags: linux, debian, hardware, restore, proxmox

Good afternoon, I'm asking for help in recovering damaged metadata after a 220V drop on the server, when the power was restored and the server booted up, I got an error in the Proxmox panel

```
activating LV 'pve/data' failed: Check of pool pve/data failed (status:1). Manual repair required! (500)
```

then booted from LiveCD debian mounted corrupted metadata and tried to repair

```
root@debian:/home/user# lvchange -ay /dev/pve/data_tdata
    Do you want to activate component LV in read-only mode? [y/n]: y
    Allowing activation of component LV.
root@debian:/home/user# lvs
      LV                                        VG                     Attr       LSize    Pool Origin                                    Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  vm-102-disk-0                             local-hdd-volume1-pve1 -wi-a-----   50.00g
  vm-103-disk-0                             local-hdd-volume1-pve1 -wi-a-----  250.00g
  vm-104-disk-0                             local-hdd-volume1-pve1 -wi-a-----  150.00g
  vm-108-disk-0                             local-hdd-volume1-pve1 -wi-a-----   20.00g
  vm-109-disk-0                             local-hdd-volume1-pve1 -wi-a-----  160.00g
  vm-110-disk-0                             local-hdd-volume1-pve1 -wi-a-----   20.00g
  base-101-disk-0                           pve                    Vri---tz-k   20.00g data
  base-105-disk-0                           pve                    Vri---tz-k   15.00g data
  data                                      pve                    twi---tz-- <858.97g
  root                                      pve                    -wi-a-----   30.00g
  snap_vm-106-disk-0_Installed              pve                    Vri---tz-k   15.00g data
  snap_vm-106-disk-0_Installed_CspAndVipnet pve                    Vri---tz-k   15.00g data
  swap                                      pve                    -wi-a-----    8.00g
  vm-100-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   20.00g data
  vm-100-disk-1                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   60.00g data
  vm-102-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   20.00g data
  vm-103-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   30.00g data
  vm-104-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   25.00g data
  vm-106-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   15.00g data snap_vm-106-disk-0_Installed_CspAndVipnet
  vm-107-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   20.00g data
  vm-108-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   30.00g data
  vm-109-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   35.00g data
  vm-110-disk-0                             pve                    Vwi---tz--   20.00g data

root@debian:/home/user# vgs
  VG                     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  local-hdd-volume1-pve1   1   6   0 wz--n-    3.27t  <2.64t
  pve                      1  17   0 wz--n- <930.50g <16.00g

root@debian:/home/user# ls -la /dev/mapper/ | grep -v vm
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     240 Mar 29 17:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root    3700 Mar 29 17:48 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Mar 29 17:35 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mar 29 17:48 pve-data_tdata -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mar 29 17:35 pve-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mar 29 17:35 pve-swap -> ../dm-0

root@debian:/home/user# thin_dump --repair /dev/mapper/pve-data_tdata > repaired.xml
The following field needs to be provided on the command line due to corruption in the superblock: transaction id

root@debian:/home/user# thin_check /dev/mapper/pve-data_tdata
examining superblock
  superblock is corrupt
    bad checksum in superblock, wanted 2018675394
```

however, I don’t know how to specify the transaction id and, most importantly, what id - where to find it

Answer (score 0):

im also facing this issue
SK ERROR: activating LV 'pve/data' failed:   Check of pool pve/data failed (status:1). Manual repair required!

anyone can help me.pls

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/446921)